# obtener el total de las sumas en arreglo bidimensional

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

Creo un arreglo bidimensional de 4x5 donde lo lleno de valores aleatorios a excepción de los últimos valores tanto de renglones y columnas, para después llenarlos por el total de la suma de cada renglón y columna. El código que utilicé me funciona, pero no me da el total de las sumas entre los totales (el último valor de mi arreglo [3][4]). Me siento atorado y no pude encontrarle solución a mi problema, alguna idea del por qué no está funcionando como debería? algún consejo?. Muchas gracias por su atención de antemano, y a continuación les dejo el código:

´´´

```
public class Main {
private static int m [][] = new int [4][5];
private static int sc = 0, sr = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //relleno con números aleatorios
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length-1; j++) {
             m[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);    
            } 
        }
        
        //imprimo para saber que dejo espacio para los totales
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(m[i][j]+" ");    
            } 
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        
        //operación para calcular totales de renglones y columnas
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                if (j<m[i].length-1) {
                sr = sr+m[j][i];
                }
                sc = sc+m[i][j];
                if (j==m[i].length-1) {
                    m[i][j] = sc;
                    m[j-1][i] = sr;
                    sr = 0;
                    sc = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        
        //imprimo para ver totales
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ["+m[i][j]+"]  ");    
            } 
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }    
}//aquí termina el código
```

´´´
Como pueden ver en la imagen siguiente, el único valor que está mal es el último, en donde debería de mostrarme la suma de los totales.

[image: Como pueden ver, el único valor que está mal es el último, en donde debería de mostrarme la suma de los totales.]

Answer (score 0):

haciendo ajuste del código, queda así.

```
        int acumulador = 0;
    //operación para calcular totales de renglones y columnas
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            if (j<m[i].length-1) {
            sr = sr+m[j][i];
            }
            sc = sc+m[i][j];
            if (j==m[i].length-1) {
                if(i != m.length-1)
                {
                    acumulador += sc;
                }
                m[i][j] = sc;
                m[j-1][i] = sr;
                sr = 0;
                sc = 0;
            }
            if(i == m.length-1 && j==m[i].length-1)
            {
                m[i][j] = acumulador;
            }   
        }
    }
```

Asigne un acumulador para ir registrando la suma de cada columnas finales, y una vez concluida ambos ciclos, asigne al elemento [N][N].